# PaperJS Canvas Background Filling Colour

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am doing the following:

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">
fill_canvas(set_of_clicked_points){
//code which correctly fills up colour for static array
context.putImageData(imageData, 0,0); 
//
}


alert(set_of_clicked_points);
} 
var cells=new Array();
function onMouseDown(event) {
var myCircle = new Path.Circle(event.point, 3);
myCircle.fillColor = 'black';
set_of_clicked_points.push(event.point.x);
set_of_clicked_points.push(event.point.y);
fill_canvas(set_of_clicked_points){

 }
</script>
```

Now my script is working perfectly till the alert(set_of_clicked_points); After that the background becomes white again where as it should be differently coloured according to my function. How can i get this done?

Does PaperJS flush the background of a canvas at regular intervals?

Answer (score 1):

The curly brackets in your code do not appear to be matched.

- line 2, open
- line 6, close
- line 10, close
- line 12, open
- line 17, open
- line 19, close

The close curly bracket on line 10 does not match an open curly bracket, and the open curly bracket on line 12 does not have a matching close curly bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Any direct drawing on the canvas through context-2d drawing commands will be wiped on the next redraw.. Paper.js draws the view after executing the script, and then after each onFrame / onMouse(Up/Down/etc) event. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with your script?

Comment: i am trying to draw centers of cells using mouse downs on the canvas, create a list of coordinates of the cell centers and using them draw the voronoi diagram